# stsadm -o deleteweb access denied

Tags: delete, sub-site

I am trying to remove a subsite with Sharepoint Management shell 2013

stsadm -o deleteweb -url `http://mysharepoint/testsubsite`

and I get **Access denied**.

Note: if I point  to `http://mysharepoint/testsubsite` with the browser I get "page not
found".

Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: guessing your running the powershell shell as administrator? Otherwise it might be possible the account your using doesn't have rights to delete the subsite?

Comment: If there is UAC enabled on the server, perhaps you need run SharePoint Management shell "run as" administrator.